# Launch Summernote Popover on Other Events

Tags: summernote

Using Summernote in airMode, the popover toolbar launches on a mouseUp event.

Is there a way to make it launch on other events (specifically, mouseEnter)?

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a hack, and risks being broken on new releases, but it does the job. Put this code in the Summernote onInit event:

```
     callbacks: {
         onInit: function () {
             let summernote = $(this).data("summernote");      // Get the summernote data object

              $(summernote.layoutInfo.editable).mouseenter(function (ev) {
                  summernote.modules.airPopover.$popover.css({
                      display: 'block',                        // Set the css to display the popover
                      left: ev.clientX - 20,                   // Offsets to position popover relative to pointer
                      top: ev.clientY + 10
                   });
               });

               $(summernote.layoutInfo.editable).mouseleave(function () {
                   setTimeout(function () {
                       // Delay so that moving over popover doesn't immediately close it 
                       summernote.modules.airPopover.hide(); },1000); 
                    });
                }
            }
       }
```

Does the job, but I'd prefer something actually supported by the library.